# When making roblox art hats are missing in render

Tags: rendering

[image]

When trying to render my character, the render loads but the hats are not there as shown in the picture. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Is the hat disabled in Render?